# Pass parameter to controller from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my routes file, I have;

```
Route::get('/{token}/student', [
    'uses' => 'SurveyController@resumeSurvey',
    'as' => 'student',
]);


Route::get('/{token}/city', [
    'uses' => 'SurveyController@resumeSurvey',
    'as' => 'city',
]);
```

So the route is either "student" or "city". How do I determine which one in my controller method? Should I even be structuring my routes like this? Should I just point them to two different methods?

I can easily pass in `{token}` for example with just;

```
public function resumeSurvey($token)
{
```

Comment: Whats wrong with using two different methods?

Comment: Technically nothing. But I'd like to keep my routes file as small as possible. I did see the `$request->path()` method for the `Request` class. I can `explode()` from that I guess.

Comment: if you have same logic for both routes you can use one method for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a controller you can get a current route name by getting a route object `Illuminate\Routing\Route`, at first place, then calling its method `getName`.

The next two ways are the same.

```
public function resumeSurvey($token)
{
    $routeName = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName();

    $routeName = $this->getRouter()-> getCurrentRoute()->getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use different methods if you would like different things to do.

Example:

```
Route::get('/{token}/student', [
    'uses' => 'SurveyController@resumeStudent',
    'as' => 'student',
]);


Route::get('/{token}/city', [
    'uses' => 'SurveyController@resumeCity',
    'as' => 'city',
]);
```

And in your controller you should have two methods:

```
public function resumeStudent($token) {

}

public function resumeCity($token) {

}
```

Then your first route goes to **resumeStudent** and the ohter route to **resumeCity**.